# Sharepoint 2013 online app custom action allowed locations?

Tags: 2013, app, custom-action

I'm trying to add list settings action to host web in SharePoint app
like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <CustomAction Id="b11d2208-f853-4c77-8d0c-2e73ddad007c.ListSettingsCustomAction2"

                RegistrationType="ContentType"
                RegistrationId="0x"

                Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.ListEdit"
                Sequence="10001"
                Title="ListSettingsCustomAction2">
    <UrlAction Url="~appWebUrl/Pages/Default.aspx?{StandardTokens}&amp;SPListItemId={ItemId}&amp;SPListId={ListId}" />
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

but I get that location is not valid error. So ok, but is there some list of allowed locations for host web customactions? I can't seem to find it on msdn or anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, and it is as unfortunate as i feared http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj997101(v=office.15).aspx